# The picture is not aliging on my webpage properly

Tags: html, css

Whatever image i add multiplies and now there are multiple boxes of the same image pls
someone help me this is frustrating
here is my css code:

.center {

display: block;

margin-left: auto;

margin-right: auto;

width: auto;

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Your body will start from here,

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="img" style="width:50%;">
```